# If Else statement logic

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm doing a little text based game and one of my if/else statement are not giving me the expected results. When the user loses it immediately jumps to "Game Over!" It is supposed to say monsterName + " has defeated you!" then jump to game over.

Could you guys help point out my logic error?

```
// Main Game Loop
while (playerHealth > 0 && monsterHealth > 0)
{
    bool playerAct = askAction();

    if (playerAct == true)// User attacks
    {
        monsterHealth = monsterHealth - playerAtk;
        if (monsterHealth < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(monsterName + " falls to the ground, defeated. Congradulation, " + name + "!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(monsterName + " takes a mighty swing back at you!");
            playerHealth = playerHealth - monsterAtk;
        }
    }                
    else// User defends
    {
        playerHealth = playerHealth - defendAtk;
        if (playerHealth < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(monsterName + " has defeated you!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(monsterName + " swings at you. It glances off your defenses.");
        }
    }               
}

// End Game
Console.WriteLine("Game Over!");
Console.ReadLine();
```

I think that is the relevant code, but just in case, here is the whole program.

```
namespace textBasedGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        //Variables
        string name;
        string monsterName;
        int playerAtk = 5;
        int monsterAtk = 2;
        int defendAtk = 1;
        int playerHealth = 2;
        int monsterHealth = 3;

        // Gathers information from the user
        Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("What is your enemies name?");
        monsterName = Console.ReadLine();

        //Story Intro
        Console.WriteLine("You are hunting in the swamp and in the darkness of the overgrowth you see a movement.");
        Console.WriteLine("You creep closer to the silouette.");
        Console.WriteLine("A little closer....");
        Console.WriteLine("It looks familiar....");
        Console.WriteLine("It is " + monsterName + "!!!");
        Console.WriteLine("Now is your chance!");

        // Main Game Loop
        while (playerHealth > 0 && monsterHealth > 0)
        {
            bool playerAct = askAction();

            if (playerAct == true)// User attacks
            {
                monsterHealth = monsterHealth - playerAtk;
                if (monsterHealth < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(monsterName + " falls to the ground, defeated. Congradulation, " + name + "!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(monsterName + " takes a mighty swing back at you!");
                    playerHealth = playerHealth - monsterAtk;
                }
            }                
            else// User defends
            {
                playerHealth = playerHealth - defendAtk;
                if (playerHealth < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(monsterName + " has defeated you!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(monsterName + " swings at you. It glances off your defenses.");
                }
            }               
        }

        // End Game
        Console.WriteLine("Game Over!");
        Console.ReadLine();            
    }

    static bool askAction()//Displays HP and asks for user action. Returns true or false
    {
        bool move;

        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?(type: attack or defend)");
        string playerAction = Console.ReadLine();

        if (playerAction == "attack")
        {
            return move = true;
        }
        else
        {
            return move = false;
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what results you are getting and what is the expected result

Comment: How are we supposed to know what is "expected results" from your perspective?

Comment: Incorrect. According to your code it is supposed to say monsterName has defeated you *ONLY* if the player's move is to DEFEND. Put the 'monster has defeated you just before the 'Game over' line

Comment: That is true. I need to add something in for when the player loses but doesn't defend on the last turn. 

This is why I love you guys so much. Thanks!

Comment: Tip: Comparing a boolean value to `true`, e.g. `if (playerAct == true)` is redundant. Just use `if (playerAct)` or, for the opposite case, `if (!playerAct)`. After all, you didn't write `if ((playerHealth > 0 ) == true && ...`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
while (playerHealth > 0 && monsterHealth > 0)

if (playerHealth < 0)
```

The `while` loop continues as long as the player's health is above zero. The `if` statement fires when their health is below zero. What happens if their health is **exactly zero**?

Comment: Hah, I didn't think of that.

That will solve this. Give me a minute and I'll accept the answer. 

Thanks so much!!

Comment: This is the answer, you'll have to use <= or >= comparisons.

Comment: Or `if (playerHealth <= 0)` instead. Considering if you have no health, you die anyway.

Comment: It could be that you need to be -1 to die, many games use that rule D&D being the most famous. 0 is just unconscious, you only die if you go in to the negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

First, I corrected this function...Basically you don't need the boolean "move", you're creating it for nothing, since you are not using it in the function.

When your function is a "bool", it returns a "bool". In other words, you can do

```
return true;
```

or

```
return false;
```

no need for

```
return move = true;
```

Try this instead:

```
static bool askAction()//Displays HP and asks for user action. Returns true or false
{
    Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?(type: attack or defend)");
    string playerAction = Console.ReadLine();

    if (playerAction == "attack")
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is your main loop. I guess that your monster dies at 0 health, so I changed the sign

```
while (playerHealth > 0 && monsterHealth > 0)
{
    bool playerAct = askAction();

    if (playerAct == true)// User attacks
    {
        monsterHealth = monsterHealth - playerAtk;
        if (monsterHealth <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(monsterName + " falls to the ground, defeated. Congradulation, " + name + "!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(monsterName + " takes a mighty swing back at you!");
            playerHealth = playerHealth - monsterAtk;
        }
    }                
    else// User defends
    {
        playerHealth = playerHealth - defendAtk;
        if (playerHealth <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(monsterName + " has defeated you!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(monsterName + " swings at you. It glances off your defenses.");
        }
    }               
}
```

Oh and by the way, at the end of the program, you say "Game Over", but what if the player won?

Comment: Lot's of great suggestions. If I had the reputation I would up vote this. 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The only logical error I see is, you have `monsterHealth = 2` and `playerAtk = 5`, so the monster is dead in every first attack and also `monsterAtk = 2;` and `playerHealth=2`. Similarly player dies on first attack. So it has become a one move game.

Then for defending, after player health is zero it exists without printing.